# C++11 g++ strangeness (using defaulted template, lambda & remove_if)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I have encountered some really weird g++ behaviour and would appreciate some help.
So I would like to present three almost similar pieces of code:

```
class Foo 
{
    public:

    template<typename T = char>
    bool Moo(std::function<bool()> f = [](){ return true; }) const
    {
        std::string str2 = "Text\n with\tsome \t  whitespaces\n\n";
        str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin(), str2.end(),
                        [](char x){return true;}), str2.end());
        // just to do something
        f = 0;
        return f();
    };
};

int main(int argc, char **args) 
{
    Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
    return myFoo->Moo<>();
}
```

This will produce 3 errors:

- default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘Foo::Moo(std::function) const::__lambda1’ [](char x){return true;})
- no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Moo()’
- template argument deduction/substitution failed

Now if we change the parameter of Moo to a trivial type *or* if we take out the lambda inside the function body (by taking out the whole line with "str.erase") the code compiles without errors!

Changing the parameter to trivial type:

```
class Foo 
{
    public:

    template<typename T = char>
    bool Moo(bool f = true) const
    {
        std::string str2 = "Text\n with\tsome \t  whitespaces\n\n";
        str2.erase(std::remove_if(str2.begin(), str2.end(),
                        [](char x){return true;}), str2.end());
        // just to do something
        f = 0;
        return f;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char **args) 
{
    Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
    return myFoo->Moo<>();
}
```

Removing the line with "str.erase":

```
class Foo 
{
    public:

    template<typename T = char>
    bool Moo(std::function<bool()> f = [](){ return true; }) const
    {
        std::string str2 = "Text\n with\tsome \t  whitespaces\n\n";
        // just to do something
        f = 0;
        return f();
    };
};

int main(int argc, char **args) 
{
    Foo* myFoo = new Foo();
    return myFoo->Moo<>();
}
```

So what is going on here? Why does the combination of the "remove_if-lambda" in the function body ("str.erase" line) and the "defaulted-lambda function" in the function parameter list produce errors regarding the "defaulted template parameter" in the function header?

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using? IIRC there have been bugs related to lambdas as default arguments..

Comment: Compiles fine (and works "as expected") on [clang++3.5 trunk 198621](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d71fa6bd5f1f7659)

Comment: I have been using g++ 4.8.1 but I see there is the 4.8.2 now so Im gonna try that too and let you know.

Comment: @BM hasn't been fixed in g++ 4.9 either.

Comment: hadnt tried it with clang so if it still fails with g++4.9 then I guess we have an official bug here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can close the question and confirm the issue:

The above (first) code example does not compile on g++-4.8.1, g++-4.8.2 nor g++-4.9.
It *does* compile on clang++ 3.2-7ubuntu1. I therefore and for not seeing any syntactic errors call this a bug in gcc.

I have reported the bug as Bug 59944: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59944

EDIT:
this bug has since then been fixed in gcc 4.9.2